# Trying to enumerate an array

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have `mainStack` as a `UIStackView`. This stack contains 4 `UIStackViews`. Each of these two 4 stacks contain 2 buttons. I am trying to locate these buttons by enumeration, using this code:

```
// get the subviews of the main stack
let subviews = mainStack!.arrangedSubviews as Array

// enumerate each one
for subStack in subviews as UIStackView { // 1
  let buttons = subStack.subvies

}
```

I have an error on `//1` with the message:

> Cannot convert value of type '[UIView]' to type 'UIStackView' in
>   coercion

Why is that? The subviews of the main stack are `UIStackViews`.are

any ideas?

Comment: Why are you even using NSArray instead of Swift array?

Comment: Oooops, sorry about that. 11 years using objective C. I have corrected the code but te problem persists with a different message now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"The subviews of the main stack are UIStackViews"*

The stackview may contain other UI elements also. You can use [pattern matching](https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/pattern-matching/2016/03/27/pattern-matching-1/) with the for loop like this

```
for case let stackView as UIStackView in mainStackView.arrangedSubviews  {
    for case let button as UIButton in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        button.addTarget...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why Error?**

```
for subStack in subviews as UIStackView
```

In the above line of code, `subviews` is an `Array` and you're trying to parse it to `UIStackView`. That's the reason it is giving compiler error.

**Solution:**

You can simply do like,

```
if let subviews = mainStack?.arrangedSubviews as? [UIStackView] {
    subviews.forEach { (subStack) in
        let buttons = subStack.arrangedSubviews as? [UIButton]
        //add your code here...
    }
}
```

Note: Use `if-let` to unwrap `optionals` instead of `force unwrapping(!)` them.